# combine_first with ffill for baseDf AND fillna for additionalDf

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine_first a baseDf and an additionalDf with pandas.
How can I use ffill() for the baseDf and fillna(-1) for the second?

---

for instance:
baseDf:

```
   qty total
1   10    10
2    5    15
4    4    19
6    8    27
8    2    29
```

additionalDf:

```
     val
3    400
5    150
7     60
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
   qty total   val
1   10    10    -1
2    5    15    -1
3    5    15   400
4    4    19    -1
5    4    19   150
6    8    27    -1
7    8    27    60
8    2    29    -1
```

But if I write:

```
baseDf.combine_first(additionalDf).ffill().fillna(-1)
```

I get:

```
   qty total   val
1   10    10    -1
2    5    15    -1
3    5    15   400
4    4    19   400
5    4    19   150
6    8    27   150
7    8    27    60
8    2    29    60
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just need change the position of `fillna` and `fffill`

```
baseDf.combine_first(additionalDf).fillna({'val':-1}).ffill()
Out[360]: 
    qty  total    val
1  10.0   10.0   -1.0
2   5.0   15.0   -1.0
3   5.0   15.0  400.0
4   4.0   19.0   -1.0
5   4.0   19.0  150.0
6   8.0   27.0   -1.0
7   8.0   27.0   60.0
8   2.0   29.0   -1.0
```

Comment: Excellent!
Thank you very much @Wen-Ben, it's working perfectly! I tried this previously but with fillna(), which filled the missing values in all the columns with -1... Now it's ok!